# delete data from Table1 that doesn't exist in Table2

Tags: oracle

I have 2 different tables and I want to delete records from table1 which does not exist in Tables2

Table1:

```
select col1 from Table1
```

Table2:

```
select 
    concat('A_',col1) 
from 
    Table2 
where 
    Col2 = '748' 
    and Col3 = 'D' 
    and Col4 = 'Account'
```

now I want to delete the difference from Table1...

Comment: What's the field(s) that joins the two?

Comment: there are no common cols that joins these 2 tables ...

Comment: Then how do you know which rows to delete?

Comment: Which column in table1 do you need to check doesn't exist in table2? Which column in table2?

Comment: select col1 from Table1                                                                      MINUS                                                                                               select 
    concat('A_',col1) 
from 
    Table2 
where 
    Col2 = '748' 
    and Col3 = 'D' 
    and Col4 = 'Account'

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you trying to delete records or define a set?

Comment: simple compare table1 and table2 find the difference and keep them in temp table3 and the delete, then compare table1 and table3 then delete common records from both ...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [`minus`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) operation, and an [`insert into`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php) statement.

```
insert into table3(col) (

  select col1 from Table1

  minus 

  select 
      concat('A_',col1) 
  from 
      Table2 
  where 
      Col2 = '748' 
      and Col3 = 'D' 
      and Col4 = 'Account'
)
```

Records can then be deleted from table1 using a [`delete`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/delete.php) statement like

```
delete from table1
where col1 in (
  select col1 from Table1

  minus 

  select 
      concat('A_',col1) 
  from 
      Table2 
  where 
      Col2 = '748' 
      and Col3 = 'D' 
      and Col4 = 'Account'
)
```

Comment: now here I go the difference now I need to put them in table3 how can I do that? ...and I need to delete records from table1..how can I do that ..

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table1 t1
where  not exists ( select * from table2 where  col2 || col3 || col4 = t1.col1 );
```

This will work EXCEPT for the following situation; you need to explain what you want in that case. The DELETE statement can be modified to accommodate.

If `t1.col1` is `NULL`, it will be deleted **even if** there are rows in `table2` where `col2`, `col3` and `col4` are all `NULL`. Is that situation possible (where `t1.col1` and `col2, col3, col4` in `table2` are **all** `NULL`? In that case, should the row in `t1` be kept rather than deleted?